# How to find an analytical expression for $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}x^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I've been trying to find an analytical expression (if it exists) of the followimg function:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}x^{2n}
$$
written in form of elemental functions. I've tried to write a differential equation for the series given that:
$$
f'(x) = -2x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^n}x^{2n}
$$
$$
f''(x) = 4x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+2)^n}x^{2n} + 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^n}x^{2n} - 4
$$
I've found an approximation to $f'(x)$ by saying
$$
4x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+2)^n}x^{2n} \approx -2x f'(x)
$$
For large values of $n$, hence:
$$
f''(x) = -2xf'(x) - \frac{1}{x}f'(x) - 4
$$
$$
f'(x) =\frac{2 (e^{x^2} - 1)}{x}
$$
But there is possible to find a close form for the series?

Comment: What convention are you using for the $0^0$ in the first term?

Comment: the function $\frac{e^{x^2}}x$ doesn't have a nice expression, it is $Ei(x^2)$ where $Ei = \int \frac{e^{-t}}t dt$

Comment: You likely can find an integral representation in terms of a similar integrand like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Comment: No closed form is known.  This would be no easier than the "sophomore's dream" `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream`